# Two different possibilities of a function satisfying $f(1)=f(0)+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $f(1)=f(0)+1$. Then which of the following is/are true?

(a) $f^{\prime}$ is constant.

(b) $f(2)=f(1)+1$

(c) $f^{\prime}(x)=1$ for some $x$ in $(0,1)$ .

(d) $\left|f^{\prime}(x)\right| \leq 1$ for all $x$ in $(0,1)$

Source: Indian competitive exam for M.Sc in Applied Mathematics.

We see that $f(x)=x+C$, where $C$ is a constant satisfies the hypothesis of the problem.Hence all the options will be true.

On the other hand $f(x)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)$ also satisfies the hypothesis of the problem. But this function satisfies only option $(c)$.

Comment: There is no question in this Question.

Comment: Your example shows that at most option (c) can possibly hold in all cases. Can you find a way of proving that it indeed holds ?

Comment: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) may help

Answer (score 4):

From MVT we get that there exists such $c\in (0,1)$ s.t $f’(c)=f(1)-f(0)=1$. You found an example where only c holds true, so this gives you the answer.